# publish to multiple remotes using Github for Windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Short: Is there a way we can push to multiple remotes simultaneously using Github for Windows GUI.

I am aware of the solution involving creating merged-remotes by editing the config file given here: [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations/3195446#3195446)

What I am looking for is a simple GUI functionality extending the current user-friendly 'sync' and 'publish' option of Github 4 Windows. The settings have a direct option to edit the primary remote (origin). Can I add secondary remotes via that interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way currently to publish to multiple remotes at the moment, you can only push/pull to `origin`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Such a feature will be hugely appreciated for the already awesome Git for Windows application.

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to do such a thing? What is your scenario?

Comment: I wanted to push to my personal github repo as well as an organisation repo. Also I wanted to checkout branches present in the organisation repo. and not present in my personal github repo (origin).

Comment: Why aren't you just committing to the organization repo?

Comment: The organisation repo was setup to introduce my colleagues to github and bring our work together. I was hoping to backup my commits and work into my personal repo that they can't alter accidentally. I understand that this is a specific situation but thought that a feature to easily push/pull from multiple repos might come handy in other situations also.

Comment: I also would like to do development in my organization repo the same way it's done in most open source repos, in which pull requests are opened from branches in forks of the org repo, rather than having all of the developers push to branches within the org repo.

Comment: @PaulBetts: I'd also like this functionality. My scenario is that I have an existing private Git origin (not GitHub) and I would like to publish my app to AppHarbor which would be the second origin of the same repo.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik :cool:, I think the deploy scenario is one of the useful ones to support in future versions of GitHub for Windows

Comment: @PaulBetts: Is there a feature request somewhere where one can submit such stuff?

Comment: Send in an Email to support@github.com, the dev team reads all the Windows-related ones